# Change only one item style instead everyone. There's changing all ListTile instead one

Tags: flutter, dart

After when I tapped the ListTile there should change only one item but when I tapped there changed all ListTile.

```
  class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  bool checked = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: 7,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int i) {
          child: return Container(
            decoration: new BoxDecoration(
              color: checked ? Colors.teal : Colors.white
            ),
            child: ListTile(
              onTap: () => setState(() => checked = true),
              title: Text("My product"),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: your `checked` value is evaluated for all 7 items, so all of them are either teal or white - what you need is most likely `List<bool>` with 7 elements

Comment: why not use https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/CheckboxListTile-class.html?

Answer (score 2):

Try below code,

```
class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  int checkedIndex = -1;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: 7,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int i) {
          return Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: checkedIndex == i ? Colors.teal : Colors.white
            ),
            child: ListTile(
              onTap: () => setState(() => checkedIndex = i),
              title: Text("My product"),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using number which will hold index of tapped list item instead of bool and just check `if(i == checked_index)`. In your case problem is that your bool checked don't know which item is checked because checked is global variable for your whole list.

Comment: and this only works if OP wants only one item to be checked (radio button style) - otherwise he needs an array of bools

Comment: @pskink that's true, but I think he wants that in this case. There is more then one solution for this problem

Comment: sure thing, i agree